# I am having an issue with my while loop, not too sure why

Tags: python, while-loop

I was coding a little loop to stop users from using invalid input; however, now if they enter a faulty input, it continuously asks for their input. baseLet, secLet, thirdLet, and forLet are all lists with characters in them. The code is supposed to tell if the user inputs any characters not in any of the lists and make them re-enter their input if there are.

```
enchan = list(input("Enter your runes:"))

for z in enchan:
    if not(z in baseLet or z in secLet or z in thirdLet or z in forLet):
        valid = False


x = 0
while not(valid):
    x = 0
    enchan = list(input("Invalid character entered. Enter your runes:"))
    while not(x < len(enchan)):
        valid = True
        for z in enchan:
            if not(z in baseLet or z in secLet or z in thirdLet or z in forLet):
                valid = False
            x += 1
```

Forgive me, I am fairly new to coding, and there is a chance there is a stupid mistake, but that is the main reason I am here (to learn).

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and display which part of code is executed. You can also `print( not(x < len(enchan)) )`

Comment: what is your error and what values are in your lists?

Comment: I'm not sure what `while not(x < len(enchan)):` is trying to achieve, but another way of writing this is `while len(enchan) <= x:`, but first time round the loop this will be `while len(enchan) <= 0:`, which is going to be `False` if the user has input anything.

Comment: @luigigi, there is no error, the while loop merely never ends. @Ken Y-N, thank you for asking me about that! I am still not sure what was wrong, but I replaced the ```while not(x < len(enchan)):``` with ```for x in range(len(enchan)):``` as it was meant to make the loop repeat the length of enchan. After changing this, however, the while loop was able to end. If someone could explain this to me, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Ozakriid its because you never entered the while loop. Your condition logic was wrong. you had to have it as `while x < len(enchan):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
baseLet = ['a']
secLet = ['b']
thirdLet = ['c']
forLet = ['d']
valid = False

def is_valid(input_string):
    for s in input_string:
        if not(s in baseLet or s in secLet or s in thirdLet or s in forLet):
            print('false input')
            return False
    print('valid input')
    return True

while not valid:
    enchan = list(input("Enter your runes:"))
    valid = is_valid(enchan)
```

You can use a function to check if your input is part of your lists and set a flag to stop your while loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly, and I understand it.